# Cloudinary Invalid image file exception

Tags: android, parse-platform, cloudinary

Cloudinary only has an example for how to load images from android to the cloud. However I need to upload videos. When I use the call from the sample code I get an `Invalid image file` error. Here is the call that throws the exception

```
Map cloudinaryResult=cloudinary.uploader().upload(file, uploadParams);
```

Does anyone know the call for uploading videos instead of photos? I am using Cloudinary with Parse.com

Here is the stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid image file
            at com.cloudinary.android.UploaderStrategy.callApi(UploaderStrategy.java:101)
            at com.cloudinary.Uploader.callApi(Uploader.java:22)
            at com.cloudinary.Uploader.upload(Uploader.java:55)
```

Comment: also my url only has alpha and dashes as in `abce_efgh_ijklm_nopqu_st.mp4`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should add

`uploadParams.put("resource_type", "video")`

to tell Cloudinary that you want to upload video. Or,

`uploadParams.put("resource_type", "auto")`

to let Cloudinary determine the file's content.

Comment: It would be nice if these guys included this information in their samples or documentations. This is an unnecessary barrier to entry and waste of time. Maybe I should look into their competitors :). But check and plus one to you. Thank you.

Comment: @KatedralPillon who are their competitors?...doesnt seem to be much offerings in this space...sans DIY recipes...

Comment: @KatedralPillon I couldn't agree more. The docs for their iOS github repo are terrible.

Comment: I need to upload pdf file to cloudinary i tired to use source type auto and I got Invalid resource.

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is old, for those using ***PHP/Laravel*** and still facing this issue:

### A. To upload an image:

1. In your request validation:

   'avatar' => 'mimes: jpeg, png, jpg',
2. then upload the image to Cloudinary as shown below:

   $image = Cloudinary::upload($request->file('avatar')->getRealPath(), ['folder' => 'projectName/avatar'])->getSecurePath();

### B. To upload documents and file such as csv, doc,docx, pdf, sql, txt, and zip):

- In your request validation:

  'document' => 'mimes: pdf, doc, docx, sql, txt, zip, csv'
- then upload the document or file as shown below:

$documents = Cloudinary::uploadFile($request->file('document')->getRealPath(), ['folder' => 'projectName/documents'])->getSecurePath();

**Important note.**

- Please take note of the ***"upload"*** when dealing with images
  and ***"uploadFile"*** when dealing with files and documents.
- Ensure to make the necessary settings in your Cloudinary ***"Upload
  Presets"*** settings as shown below:

[image]

Congratulations!